# Structure sentences from words of triplets saved in a 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, cpu-word

I am currently having a text with its words saved as triplets in an 2D list.

The code so far:

```
with open(r'c:\\python\4_TRIPLETS\Sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '').split()
    lines = [data[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
print(lines)
```

My 2D List:

```
[['Python', 'is', 'an'], ['interpreted,', 'high-level', 'and'], ['general-purpose', 'programming', 'language.'], ["Python's", 'design', 'philosophy'], ['emphasizes', 'code', 'readability'], ['with', 'its', 'notable'], ['use', 'of', 'significant'], ['whitespace.', 'Its', 'language'], ['constructs', 'and', 'object-oriented'], ['approach', 'aim', 'to'], ['help', 'programmers', 'write'], ['clear,', 'logical', 'code'], ['for', 'small', 'and'], ['large-scale', 'projects.']]
```

I want to create a Python code which picks one random set of these triplets, then tries to create a new random text by using the last 2 words and by choosing a triplet that starts with these two. Finally my program ends when 200 words are being written or none other triplet set can be chosen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick a random triplet:

```
import random

triplet = random.choice(lines)
last_two = triplet[1:3]
```

To then continue picking:

```
while True:
    candidates = [t for t in lines if t[0:2] == last_two]
    if not candidates:
        break

    triplet = random.choice(candidates)
    last_two = triplet[1:3]
```

I'll leave the saving of output and the length stopping criterion to you.

Comment: Mmmmmm ok. It seems to me that the text I am using is too poor in reproducing a new one based on its existing words. But for testing purposes I duplicated the sentence "Python is an interpreted" on the same txt file and I am receiving results. i.e. (['Python', 'is', 'an']) -> ['is', 'an'] -> ['is', 'an', 'interpreted'] -> ['an', 'interpreted']. I suppose I have to use a better input for my results. At least am I right this far???